# xargs + curl "Failed writing body" (cannot save more than one result to file)

Tags: linux, bash, curl, pipe, xargs

I have problem with xargs and curl.

I have url list in "urls" file, and i need to download these contents limited to first 9 lines and save all to one output file (or one file per result - doesnt matter).

```sh
xargs -P 4 -n 1 curl < urls | head -n 9 > outputfile
```

The problem is that, there only first result are saving to file, all others give a error "(23) Failed writing body". Even when i dont save results to file, there is a "(23) Failed writing body" error in console.

In sum:
I need to download first 9 lines of XXXX URLs from file, and save this to one output file, or one file per URL.

The problem exists on Cygwin (Windows 10) and MacOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline limits the output to the first 9 lines of `xargs` output. Try this instead.

```
xargs -P 4 -i sh -c 'curl {} | head -n 9' <urls >outputfile
```

This will probably mix up the output lines of parallel fetches uncontrollably. If you want to avoid that, maybe look at GNU `parallel`. If that's unacceptable, maybe write each to a separate temporary file and concatenate and delete the temporary files when the fetching is done.